# Is the network part of an IPv4 address unique?

Tags: ip, ipv4

I get that an IPv4 address can be subdivided into two parts, the network part and the host part.
In my private home network, is the network part publicly unique?, i.e., may other people have the same ipv4 address as me?

Comment: Your local private IPv4 network is most likely not unique. But private ranges are reserved for that purpose and excludet from internet routing tables. Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 1):

In your home network, the network part (*i.e.* your subnet) is almost certainly not unique.  You are probably using a private network (192.168.1.0/24) for your home network.

You are able to use the Internet because your private IP address is translated to a unique public IP address by your ISP.  If you want, you can read more about [Network Address Translation](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12540/how-nat-portforwarding-tcp-ip-works).